# How does COM find and run a DLL by late binding?

Tags: windows, com, registry

Using VBA to give an example of the question:

```
Set obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("COMlib.ClassA")
```

**How does COM find with help of the registry where COMlib.dll is located?**

**What keys does COM look at and in what order to be able to create ClassA?**

This is related to another question

[COM & Late binding in Excel/VBA: ActiveX component can't create object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319593/com-late-binding-in-excel-vba-activex-component-cant-create-object)

Answer (score 2):

The `COMlib.ClassA` has an entry in `HKCR`.

The entries under `HKCR\CLSID\guid` again has informations about the DLL to load and how to load and work with it (external server etc.) incl. type lib. etc.

There may also entries under `HKCR/TypeLib`, when the class is implemented with a dual interface...

When you register the DLL all these entries are created.

Comment: Very good information! Thank you! Do you have any tip for good reading material regarding this?

Comment: @JohanA - Note that HKCR is a merged view of HKLM\Software\Classes and HKCU\Software\Classes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) COM Registry keys are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/registry-entries